# Localhost running jquery twice?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've been working on a Rails app for months.  Today when I run the app on localhost, it seems like jquery is executing twice on each page.

I'm running on an iMac.

Some symptoms are:

1. DataTables is telling me "Cannot rein initialize DataTables"
2. Full-calendar is displaying 2 calendars on a page instead of 1
3. Bootstrap dropdown menus don't work

It's really got me baffled !!!

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1

The same app runs fine when I Cap Deploy to a Rails Virtual Server.  So, it seems to me that it has something to do with my iMac environment.

I'm not sure what code to show.  Because the jquery/javascript code seems to fire twice in all the number examples above.

Here is the view code for the calendar (the calendar now displays twice on the page):

```
<h2><%= current_user.employee.employee_full_name %> - Labor Month</h2>
<%= content_tag "div", id: "calendar", data: {employeeid: current_user.employee.id} do %>
<% end %>
```

And the coffee script:

```
$(document).ready ->

$('#calendar').fullCalendar
  ignoreTimezone: true,
  editable: true,
  defaultView: 'month',
  height: 500,
  slotMinutes: 30,
  selectable: true,
  selectHelper: true,

select: (start, end, allDay) ->
  title = $("#title")
  description = $("#description")
  hours = $("#hours")
  workorder = $("#workorder_id")
  actcode = $("#actcode_id")
  $("#dialog-form").dialog
    autoOpen: true
    height: 500
    width: 400
    modal: true
    buttons:
     "Create Labor": ->
       $.create "/events/",
         event:
           workorder_id: workorder.val(),
           actcode_id: actcode.val(),
           title: title.val(),
           description: description.val(),
           hours: hours.val()
           starts_at: "" + start,
           ends_at: "" + end,
           all_day: allDay,
           employee_id: $('#calendar').data('employeeid')
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')
       $(this).dialog "close"

      Cancel: ->
        $(this).dialog "close"

eventSources: [{
  url: '/events',
}],

timeFormat: 'h:mm t{ - h:mm t} ',
dragOpacity: "0.5"

eventDrop: (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) ->
  updateEvent(event);

eventResize: (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) ->
  updateEvent(event);

updateEvent = (the_event) ->
  $.update "/events/" + the_event.id,
    event:
      title: the_event.title,
      starts_at: "" + the_event.start,
      ends_at: "" + the_event.end,
      description: the_event.description
```

UPDATE3

```
Some gems I'm using related to javascript:
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'fullcalendar-rails'
gem 'jquery-rest-rails'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'bootstrap-editable-rails'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'
gem 'jqtree-rails'
```

UPDATE4

Is there something I should be looking at Chrome inspect element?

UPDATE5

@abhi and Wizard of Ogz said to delete the public assets or try putting this into development.rb = config.assets.debug = false .  When I added the line to the development.rb, the errors went away.

Now I'm not sure what I should do next.  I would like to be able to debug assets.

Comment: Pretty much impossible to say anything without seeing the code.

Comment: What does your scripts look like? What js libs do you import?

Comment: That looks not like jquery executing twice, but more like the jquery datatable plugin being run twice. Again, hard to say anything without some code...

Comment: Are you attaching multiple similar events to the same objects accidentally?

Comment: Possibility: you have duplicate assets, one being in app/assets and one in public/

Comment: I agree with @abhi. Rails includes assets twice after precompiling them and then attempting to run with asset debugging enabled. I simply removed the precompiled assets with `rm -rf public/assets`. If thats not an option for you then try turning asset debugging off.

Comment: I think this pre-compile is the answer.  I believe I ran a command to pre-compile while I was scrambling to get Capistrano-Passenger working.   I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: I ran this command in the terminal $ rm -rf public/assets   - I got no response - should I have gotten one?  I looked in my app directory and I now don't have an 'assets' directory under public.  I thought for sure this would fix it.  But, it's still the same errors.

Comment: I put this into development.rb =   config.assets.debug = false And the errors went away.  Now what do I do?

Comment: Wizard of Ogz - if you want to supply an answer, I'll accept it!  And THANK YOU !!

Answer (score 0):

Have you switched to turbolinks recently? There is a gem which addresses these sort of issues. (jquery.turbolinks)

> If you find that some events are being fired multiple times after using jQuery Turbolinks, you may have been binding your document events inside a $(function()) block. For instance, this example below can be a common occurrence and should be avoided:

```
/* BAD: don't bind 'document' events while inside $()! */
$(function() {
 $(document).on('click', 'button', function() { ... })
});
```

https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks#troubleshooting

But you should consider improving your question by providing more details and some code.